# Can Anyone explain me the Difference between dispatch_sync and dispatch_async?

Tags: iphone, ios

When I call dispatch_async method on the same queue two times with different task, it executes the tasks on different threads instead of same thread for both task.

```
void(^myBlock)(void) = ^{
  for(int i = 0;i < 10 ; i++)
  {
     NSLog(@"%d and current queue = %@",i,[NSThread currentThread]);   
  }
};

-(void)viewDidLoad   
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_
    DEFAULT, 0);

    dispatch_async(queue,myBlock);    
    dispatch_async(queue,myBlock);
}
```

when I run this program it creates two threads.Following is the output.

2013-09-10 17:45:20.435 ConcurrencyDemo[1331:30b] 0 and current queue = {name = (null), num = 3}
2013-09-10 17:45:20.435 ConcurrencyDemo[1331:1603] 0 and current queue = {name = (null), num = 2}
2013-09-10 17:45:20.438 ConcurrencyDemo[1331:1603] 1 and current queue = {name = (null), num = 2}
2013-09-10 17:45:20.438 ConcurrencyDemo[1331:30b] 1 and current queue = {name = (null), num = 3}
2013-09-10 17:45:20.440 ConcurrencyDemo[1331:1603] 2 and current queue = {name = (null), num = 2}
2013-09-10 17:45:20.440 ConcurrencyDemo[1331:30b] 2 and current queue = {name = (null), num = 3}
2013-09-10 17:45:20.441 ConcurrencyDemo[1331:1603] 3 and current queue = {name = (null), num = 2}
2013-09-10 17:45:20.441 ConcurrencyDemo[1331:30b] 3 and current queue = {name = (null), num = 3}
2013-09-10 17:45:20.442 ConcurrencyDemo[1331:30b] 4 and current queue = {name = (null), num = 3}
2013-09-10 17:45:20.442 ConcurrencyDemo[1331:1603] 4 and current queue = {name = (null), num = 2}
2013-09-10 17:45:20.443 ConcurrencyDemo[1331:1603] 5 and current queue = {name = (null), num = 2}
2013-09-10 17:45:20.443 ConcurrencyDemo[1331:30b] 5 and current queue = {name = (null), num = 3}
2013-09-10 17:45:20.444 ConcurrencyDemo[1331:30b] 6 and current queue = {name = (null), num = 3}
2013-09-10 17:45:20.444 ConcurrencyDemo[1331:1603] 6 and current queue = {name = (null), num = 2}
2013-09-10 17:45:20.445 ConcurrencyDemo[1331:30b] 7 and current queue = {name = (null), num = 3}
2013-09-10 17:45:20.445 ConcurrencyDemo[1331:1603] 7 and current queue = {name = (null), num = 2}
2013-09-10 17:45:20.446 ConcurrencyDemo[1331:1603] 8 and current queue = {name = (null), num = 2}
2013-09-10 17:45:20.446 ConcurrencyDemo[1331:30b] 8 and current queue = {name = (null), num = 3}
2013-09-10 17:45:20.448 ConcurrencyDemo[1331:30b] 9 and current queue = {name = (null), num = 3}
2013-09-10 17:45:20.448 ConcurrencyDemo[1331:1603] 9 and current queue = {name = (null), num = 2}

Can anyone tell me why this is happening?

Comment: Reading this may help you:https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/Reference/reference.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The assignment of dispatched blocks to threads is an internal implementation detail. You may not rely on the system using any particular thread, except for the main queue, which will always run on the main thread.

In this particular case, however, this thread situation is exactly what you should expect. The global queues, other than the main queue, are concurrent queues. So you should expect the system to create enough threads to efficiently service all of the blocks you put on it simultaneously within the limits of hardware. What did you expect to happen?

To your specific question, `dispatch_async` means "put this block on the queue and immediately return." `dispatch_sync` means "put this block on the queue, wait for it to run, and then return."

Comment: when I uses  dispatch_sync(queue,myBlock) in last line then it executes that in the main queue. Why?

Comment: It doesn't execute it on the main queue. It may execute it on the main thread (you don't check the queue in your code above; you check the thread). What specific thread it chooses to use is not your business. It probably uses the main thread because there is no need to use another in that case. Calling `dispatch_sync()` blocks the current thread, so that thread is now free to run the block you just submitted.